# How can I flush all caches on a PowerPC board?

Tags: assembly, caching, linux-kernel, cpu-cache, powerpc

I have a Linux kernel application running on an embedded PowerPC system.  I'm looking for a way to write back all modified cache lines in the processor’s internal cache to main memory and invalidate (flush) the internal caches.  I know that the x86 has an instruction that will do this (wbinvd).

Is there a way to do the same thing under PowerPC via a C function call or assembly instruction?

I know that there are PowerPC instructions like `dcbt` which will update the cache for that address, but I'm looking for something that will flush everything.